# Voice action "Set alarm..." doesn't work on HTC Desire

Tags: htc-desire, alarm, google-voice-actions

I have been trying out [Voice Actions](http://www.google.com/mobile/voice-actions/) on an HTC Desire. Actions like "Navigate to...", "Directions to..." and "Note to self..." work fine. When I try saying "Set alarm to 9 o'clock" though I get this error message:

> "Set alarm..."
>
> In order to use this feature, download the latest Clock from the Android Market.

I already have the HTC Clock application and as far as I am aware it is fully updated but I'm assuming that the HTC Clock doesn't support the voice actions. Where is the correct "Clock" application? Opening the Market and searching for "Clock" doesn't seem to show any promising results (though I have to admit that I haven't checked all 1062 hits). Has anyone got this working on an HTC Desire? What do I need to do?

Comment: I don't see "Set alarm..." in the list of Voice Actions (http://www.google.com/mobile/voice-actions/).  Are you sure it is one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for the Voice Actions to successfully set the alarm the device must contain an app that implements the `android.intent.action.SET_ALARM` intent. (Read more in the documentation of [android.provider.AlarmClock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/AlarmClock.html).) There is no guarantee that your device contains such an app (unless it's a stock Android). The situation is worse on Samsung Galaxy S II (with ICS) which by default comes with Samsung's own Clock app which seems to handle the intent but actually does not, i.e. in response to the Voice Action a blank Clock window pops up and no alarm is set. So Voice Actions won't even find out that the alarm setting task was not carried out.

The only app that I'm aware of that properly handles this intent and can be used with Voice Actions is [Alarm Clock Plus★](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vp.alarmClockPlusDock). It is likely that there are more such apps but Android Market does not make finding them easy, because it does not offer a search-by-intent feature...

Answer (score 2):

It appears that it is possible to get the "Set Alarm..." voice action working by installing a leaked version of DeskClockGoogle.apk as described on [this website](http://www.droid-life.com/2010/09/09/download-new-desk-clock-fixes-set-alarm-voice-action/). I have not tested it.

It seems that this feature is not yet officially released but is coming soon.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the clock application on the HTC Desire is one made by HTC and not Google. I believe Google is in the process of releasing their own clock application via the Market as they have done with their other apps like Maps and soon to be Gmail.